# Find and remove scripts from html page with jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I want to remove annoying ads from a web page, that on every click on link opens a link (iframe), and I think these are the scripts that I think I have to remove from the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {

            var oi, aframes;

            aframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

            for (oi = 0; oi < aframes.length; ++oi) {

                var ns = aframes[oi].getAttribute("data-src");

                if(ns != undefined && ns != '') aframes[oi].src = aframes[oi].getAttribute("data-src");

            }

        };

    </script>
<script> 

                    window.url = "http://xml.adventurefeeds.com/redirect?feed=59533&auth=1IHLhM&subid=15067&url=http%3A%2F%2Farenabg.com%2F%3Fq%3Dbest%2Bdeals&query=torrent%20%2C%20streaming%20%2C%20download%20%2C%20movie%20%2C%20games%20%2C%20gaming%20%2C%20binary%20option%20%2C%20gambling%20%2C%20betting%20%2C%20sport&default_url=http%3A%2F%2Fviralture.com"; 

                    window.arrClicks = [1, 3]; 

                </script>
<script src="http://worldsearchpro.com/popUnderResources/popUnderAdvan.js"></script>
```

Want to use jQuery script to do that because I want to use the script in violentmonkey as userscript. The problem is, that I don't know how to find/select with jQuery exactly these scripts. I would really appreciate if anyone can helps me to remove these three scripts.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't simply use an existing AdBlocker?

Comment: why toil so much, i would suggest using AdBlocker.

Comment: You don't prevent the execution of script tags by removing them.

Comment: I'm using uBlock, and I think it's the best, but how to block something that I can't select with the adblock? Well I know that I can block js url with @@ or @@|| (not sure how is with uBlock) but the other two scripts?

Comment: i have this problem in one of my site. when in admin panel. the script of another site in event lists in chrome. https://atlantai.site/atl.js this script run i dont know what is this and when or from which plugin installed here. can anyone help me